# Display Carrierwave attachment filename after form redisplays using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

In my Rails app I have multiple file input fields on the same page. I use the jQuery below to display the filenames to the users when a file is attached:

```
$(document).on('change', ':file', function() {
    var input = $(this),
        filename = input.val().replace(/^.*[\\\/]/g, '');
    $(".filename[data-input='" + this.id + "']").text(filename);
});


<span class="filename" data-input="example-marketing-material-file"></span>
```

When a validation error is thrown and the page redisplays the form, I have to get the filename from my cached hidden field as mentioned in the Carrierwave [docs](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#making-uploads-work-across-form-redisplays), the html output looks like this:

```
<input id="example-marketing-material-file-cache" name="bid[example_marketing_material_cache]" type="hidden" value="1430984214-14326-1254/Banking_Details_Reader.pdf" />
```

After a validation error occurs, how would I alter my current jQuery to pass my hidden file field values into my filename class instead?

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30114820/2811283 for correct answer to this questions. The following code was used.

```
$(document).on("page:load ready", function() {
    $files=$(".cached-filename");
    // loop over selectors and update instance
    $(".filename").text(function(idx, text) {
        return $files.eq(idx).val().replace(/^.*[\\\/]/g, '');
    })
});
```