# Display multiple attachment filenames with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the following jQuery to get the filename from my hidden field which I then append to my filename class in my HTML.

```
filenameCache = $('#example-marketing-material-file-cache').val().replace(/^.*[\\\/]/g, '');
$(".filename").text(filenameCache);

<input id="example-marketing-material-file-cache" name="bid[example_marketing_material_cache]" type="hidden" value="1430984214-14326-1254/Banking_Details_Reader.pdf" />
```

However, I have three file attachments on the same page. I could just repeat this code three times changing the class and ID names for each but this is not very DRY. What is the best way of getting the filenames for each attachment field without repeating myself?

Comment: maybe giive class and use each() function?

Comment: Thank you for the comment could you please provide an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the file fields a common class like of "file_upload" , can use `text(fn)` to loop over the filename fields and update instances

```
$files=$('.file_upload');
// loops over all in selector and updates instances
$(".filename").text(function(idx , txt){
    return $files.eq(idx).val().replace(/^.*[\\\/]/g, '');
});
```

This assumes that you have 3 of each and they have matching indexing in page

If there is only one filename field

```
$(".filename").text(function(idx , txt){
    return $.map($files, function(el){
          return el.value.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/g, '');
    }).join(", ");
});
```

Comment: Great answer thank you. Silly question but idx is the index correct?

Answer (score 0):

Give them a common clas, capture them, and loop over them.

Since you are using jquery you can use [.each](http://api.jquery.com/each)

HTML

```
<input class="filename-input" value="some.pdf"/>
<input class="filename-input" value="other.pdf"/>
<input class="filename-input" value="another.pdf"/>
```

JS

```
var filenames = [];
jQuery(".filename-input").each(function(){
   filenames.push( jQuery(this).val().replace(/^.*[\\\/]/g, '') );
});
jQuery(".filename").text(filenames.join(" "));
```

Demo

```js
var filenames = "";
jQuery(".filename-input").each(function(){
  filenames += jQuery(this).val().replace(/^.*[\\\/]/g, '')+" ";
});
jQuery("#log").text(filenames);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="filename-input" type="hidden" value="some.pdf"/>
<input class="filename-input" type="hidden" value="other.pdf"/>
<input class="filename-input" type="hidden" value="another.pdf"/>    

<div id="log"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<div class="filename"></div>
<div id="container">
<input id="example-marketing-material-file-cache1" name="bid[example_marketing_material_cache]" type="hidden" value="1430984214-14326-1254/Banking_Details_Reader.pdf" />
<input id="example-marketing-material-file-cache2" name="bid[example_marketing_material_cache]" type="hidden" value="1430984214-14326-1254/Banking_Details_Reader.pdf" />
<input id="example-marketing-material-file-cache3" name="bid[example_marketing_material_cache]" type="hidden" value="1430984214-14326-1254/Banking_Details_Reader.pdf" />
```

js:

```
var inputs = $('#container input');
var fileNames = [];
$.each(inputs,function(index,input){

var value = $(input).val();
if(value){
    fileNames.push(value.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/g, ''));
}  

});

$(".filename").text(fileNames.join('|'));
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c3xxejsn/)